# Mongodb Query in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new mongodb and node.js .Need to get one particular claim  in case if the records has multiple claims . Can any one suggest on this ?
Like this I have multiple records with same claim but need to get one particular claim based on Data . Can anyone suggest on this ,

Data:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "Claim" : "XXX2000", 
        "policy" : "701A0P", 
        "peril" : "earthquake", 
        "insured" : "ABC", 
        "line" : "211", 
        "code" : "65"
    }

{ 
    "_id" : {
         "Claim" : "XXX2000", 
        "policy" : "701A0o", 
        "peril" : "earthquake1", 
        "insured" : "ABD", 
        "line" : "271", 
        "code" : "69"
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "Claim" : "XXX2000",
        "policy" : "701B0o", 
        "peril" : "earthquake2", 
        "insured" : "ACD", 
        "line" : "201", 
        "code" : "99"
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
         "Claim" : "XXX2000", 
        "policy" : "781A0o", 
        "peril" : "earthquake9", 
        "insured" : "BBD", 
        "line" : "871", 
        "code" : "39"
    }
}
```

required Data :

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
         "Claim" : "XXX2000", 
        "policy" : "781A0o", 
        "peril" : "earthquake9", 
        "insured" : "BBD", 
        "line" : "871", 
        "code" : "39"
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain your query

Comment: I have  a multiple records with same "Claim" but in lined data is different (policy ,peril, insured,line , code ) .Need to get the only one record   { 
    "_id" : {
         "Claim" : "XXX2000", 
        "policy" : "781A0o", 
        "peril" : "earthquake9", 
        "insured" : "BBD", 
        "line" : "871", 
        "code" : "39"
    }
}  Please let me know how to get the one record with the claim

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({
  "_id.Claim": "XXX2000",
  "_id.policy": "781A0o",
  "_id.peril": "earthquake9",
  "_id.insured": "BBD",
  "_id.line": "871",
  "_id.code": "39"
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/hGHwF6_7afH

Comment: I have 1 lakh records which contain different claims with different in lined data .Need to get different claims with the particular records not one record .I have just provided an example. Could you please suggest ?

Comment: let me explain you want to get all doc with specific `line`  ?

Comment: I am sorry , could not explain properly .I want to get all docs with specific Claims(with specific data) ,it means if collection has  a  "n" number of Claims ,need to get the specific data with the claims (without duplicates but with specific data . I hope this is clear

Comment: Can you please help me on the query

Comment: yeah , let me ask question , how you find your data in db according to which field ?

Comment: I need data based on claim

Comment: so when you want search {claim : "XXX2000"} it will return all data that theirs claim id is "XXX2000" , its ok ?

Comment: An example is provided here , Need to get the data based on different claims from the 1 lakh records